# How to integrate $\int (2)^2+(2-cos^{-1}\sqrt{x})^2dx$

Tags: integration

I went on to calculate and I just stopped midway because it was getting pretty long. Is there a shorter way to integrate $arccos$ or is the integration for this is just really tedious?

$$\int (2)^2+(2-cos^{-1}\sqrt{x})^2dx$$

is it likewise for the integration when the $arccos$ is replaced by $arcsin$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\cos^{-1}\sqrt x=y\implies x=(\cos y)^2=\dfrac{1+\cos2y}2\implies dx=-\sin2y\ dy$

and $\cos2y=2x-1$

As $\sqrt x\ge0,0\le y\le\dfrac\pi2,\sin2y=2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$

$$I=\int(a-\cos^{-1}\sqrt x)^2\ dx=-\int(a-y)^2\sin2y\ dy$$

Integrating by parts,

$$I=(a-y)^2\int(-\sin2y)\ dy-\int\left(\dfrac{d(y-a)^2}{dy}\int(-\sin2y)\ dy\right)dy$$

$$=\dfrac{(y-a)^2\cos2y}2-\dfrac12\int(y-a)\cos2y\ dy$$

Integrate by parts,
$$J=\int(y-a)\cos2y\ dy$$
$$=(y-a)\int\cos2y\ dy-\int\left(\dfrac{d(y-a)}{dy}\cdot\int\cos2y\ dy\right)dy=?$$

Comment: @sallyg, Please find this version.

Comment: On the first line, you have $dx = - \sin 2y dx$; on the last, you have two iterated integrals, each one with $dy$. Why not fix the notation?

Comment: @AlexM., Thanks for your feedback. The first line has been rectified. The issue with the last line is not clear.  I used  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Strategy

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(x\right)=\int\left(2^2+\arccos\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)\space\text{d}x=2^2\int1\space\text{d}x+\int\arccos\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\space\text{d}x$$

Now substitute $u=\sqrt{x}$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\space\text{d}x$, after that use integration by parts:

$$\int\arccos\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\space\text{d}x=2\int u\arccos(u)\space\text{d}u=u^2\arccos(u)+\int\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\space\text{d}u$$

Comment: sorry i've had some typo, i forgot to put in more values. pls look at the qn again. thank u for the help!